# In WebLogic world, are managed servers just Weblogic servers?

Tags: weblogic, application-server, middleware

I read from Oracle's documentation, and it seems that managed servers are basically WebLogic servers(the application server we download from their site). But I also watched a youtube video, which says that SOA suite, service bus are the managed servers. So I am a little confused. Could someone explained this to me?

Comment: You question does not make sense yet. Please try to state exactly what you are doing, and what goes wrong/is unclear

Comment: @michelz sorry, it's just some terminology confusion.

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic server isn't even a managed server, it's simply an application layer. So no, managed servers are not all WebLogic servers, although a very small percentage of them do use WebLogic.

Comment: `One instance of WebLogic Server in each domain acts as an Administration Server. The Administration Server provides a central point for managing a WebLogic Server domain. All other WebLogic Server instances in a domain are called Managed Servers.` It's from Oracle's website. I wonder if this is their official definition of **managed server**...

Comment: @Yang, that quote does not contradict anything I've said. I believe the problem from your perspective is, as you stated in a comment, that it's just confusing terminology. Oracle's terminology isn't the same as what the rest of the planet recognises as managed servers, which is where a third party manages servers on behalf of its clients.